# Selecting data from an array as an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myObj = [
            {"a":"1", "b":"2"},
            {"c":"3", "c":"4"},
            {"d":"5", "e":"6"}
        ];
```

What is the best solution to pick one of the rows? I have this function below which convert the Object to array, but it returns indexes, though I need the full row.

```
var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
            return value;
        });
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: “_unclear what you’re asking_”

Comment: Sorry, you right I accidentally pushed the post. I updated the question.

Comment: what should  your output look like? Can you show desired output?

Comment: Providing I am using the myObj from above I would like to able to return this: {"a":"1", "b":"2"} or the next one from within the myObj, but as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myObj = [{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}, {
  "c": "3",
  "c": "4"
}, {
  "d": "5",
  "e": "6"
}];


var reformattedArray = myObj.map(function(value, index, array) { 
   return Object.values(value);
});

console.log(reformattedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired output is, for example:

```
[
  "a",
  "b"
]
```

Do:

```js
var myObj = [
            {"a":"1", "b":"2"},
            {"c":"3", "c":"4"},
            {"d":"5", "e":"6"}
        ];

var newArr = myObj.map(row => Object.keys(row));

console.log(newArr[0]);
```